# Emacs key bindings in DrRacket?

Tags: emacs, racket, key-bindings

How are we supposed to configure DrRacket so that it does not use Emacs key bindings? Like I type C-s and it just saves the code instead of bringing up the search line. Or I use C-x C-f and it won't open another file. The DrRacket documentation claims to not use Emacs bindings but it obviously does.

Comment: just to be clear, you were actually wanting to turn *off* the emacs behavior, while the accepted answer describes how to turn it *on*, right?  (Either way, I understand why the answer is accepted since the description of how to turn it on also makes it clear how to turn it off, but the apparent mismatch confused me initially.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want to *disable* the check box, **Enable keybindings in menus**.

Unfortunately this checkbox is a bit buried:

1. Open the Racket **Preferences** dialog.
2. Click the **Editing** tab.
3. There's a row of sub-tabs for that. Click the **General** sub-tab.
4. A few items down you should see the **Enable keybindings in menus** check box. Un-check it.